# convert log(log(x)) to x-based power

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I'd like to convert `log(log(x))` to x-based power (I mean $x^{something}$). How can I do that?

Comment: Just confirming, because some people mean different things by $\log(x)$: Is this base-10 log, or the natural log?

Comment: It doesn't really matter - I know how to convert logarithm base. But I meant natural logarithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log(\log(x)) = x^{\log(\log(\log(x)))/\log(x)}$$

follows after using the fact that

$$x = e^{\log x}$$

and a change-of-base.